# Pandas Set Data on set of indexes and condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Having trouble setting data on a set of indexes and a condition at the same time. What's the proper way to do the following?

Also, for this example, the `df.index` doesn't serve any purpose. Please assume that it represents another pandas DataFrame/Series.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([{'val1': 30, 'val2': 40}, {'val1': 40, 'val2': 20}, {'val1': 50, 'val2': 10}])

# I can do this
df['val1'][df['val2'] == 40] = 1
print df


       val1  val2
    0     1    40
    1    40    20
    2    50    10




# I can even do this
# Sets everything since full index is passed in (same as df['val1'] = 1)
df['val1'].loc[df.index] = 1
print df


       val1  val2
    0     1    40
    1     1    20
    2     1    10




# But I cannot do this?
df['val1'].loc[df.index][df['val2'] == 20] = 1
print df


       val1  val2
    0    30    40
    1    40    20
    2    50    10
```

This is using pandas 0.19.2

Comment: What is `.loc[df.index]` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have the same problem where I want to select rows by both their index and specific conditions. Not sure if I found the best solution but here is my thought: **I will combine my row selection into one boolean array and then pass it to `.loc` or `.iloc` or `[]`.** If you actually want to select all rows, your `df.index` is really unnecessay. Otherwise, I assume you can convert your selection into a list of index, such as `[1, 2]`. I modified your example:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([{'val1': 30, 'val2': 20}, {'val1': 40, 'val2': 20}, 
                       {'val1': 50, 'val2': 10}])
print df

   val1  val2
0    30    20
1    40    20
2    50    10

# Set data
row_selection = (df['val2'] == 20) & df.index.isin([1, 2])
df['val1'][row_selection] = 1
print df

   val1  val2
0    30    20
1     1    20
2    50    10
```

To clarify it a little bit:

- Row 1 remains unchanged even though its `'val2'` is `20`;
- Row 3 remains unchanged even though row 3 (`df.index.isin([1, 2])`) was selected;
- Column `'val2'` remains unchanged;
- Only row 2, `'val1'` is changed.
- You can certainly combine multiple conditions in this way.

Comment: Is it necessary to do `as_matrix`? It should perform the `and` regardless between the two arrays.

Comment: Also, any idea with the performance implications between doing `df.loc[myindexes]` vs. `df.isin[myindexes]`?

Comment: @jab Yes, you are right. `as_matrix` is not necessary. Just updated my post.

Comment: @jab Sorry, I don't have any clear idea about the performance. I'm still new for pandas. Maybe you can test with your specific index. I'm not sure what you want to do. For me, making a boolean index seems to be the only proper way to combine row index with conditions. Suggestions are welcome.